# Google Analytics 4: Is it possible to make the new gtag code work with the old analytics.js?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, steam

My issue is with the static GA code on the Steam store page.

Steam supports only the analytics.js implementation, and there is no way for me to change the code to a newer GA4 implementation.

All that Steam allows to game developers is to change the tracking id for the store page, but they still use the old analytics.js:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxx-1', 'auto', {
        'sampleRate': 0.4               });
    ga('set', 'dimension1', true );
    ga('set', 'dimension2', 'External' );
    ga('set', 'dimension3', 'application' );
    ga('set', 'dimension4', "application\/app" );
    ga('send', 'pageview' );

</script>
```

Is it possible to use the new GA4 gtag measurement ID with this old implementation? Would using it instead of the UA-xxxxxx-1 in analytics.js work?

Comment: you need to use the new GA4 tracking code not the old tracking code.

Comment: @DaImTo Yes, that is my question - would simply replacing the old UA-XXXX-1 ga code with the new GA4 gtag ID work, or does google require the new gtag library also? Because Steam has only the old ga from analytics.js

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4

Comment: @DaImTo Yeah I've read that. I have no way to replace the old ga script code with the new gtag script code. Is it still possible to only replace the ID for it to work?

Comment: GA4 and universal analytics are completely different things.   I find it highly unlikely that it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, it is not enough to change the code from `UA-` to `G-` as everything else in the snippet and events is also different.

Anyway, the best solution is not to replace the code but to trace in parallel with both, then leave the 'old' UA and add the new trace with GA4. In this way you do not lose the history, moreover the two systems are completely different and not comparable.